# can rundeck accept input from slack to run a specific job with a parameter provided by the slack user?

Tags: slack, rundeck

I am trying to find a way to make rundeck interactive with a slack channel such that someone could send a note to the channel and it would go to Rundeck and run a job with a parameter supplied by the user.

I have a plugin already which goes in the reverse direction giving status from the rundesk jobs to the slack channel, but I'd also like the reverse.

Does anyone know of a feature/integration like the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to do that is to create a Rundeck webhook and call it from Slack creating a slash command. Take a [look](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/notifications/webhooks.html) at how Rundeck Webooks works and how to [enable](https://api.slack.com/interactivity/slash-commands) interactivity with Slack.

Also, you have a legacy [way](https://api.slack.com/tutorials/your-first-slash-command) to call custom curl commands (to call [Rundeck API](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/api/rundeck-api.html), [here](https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/95797/rundeck/7TNfX9k?version=latest) some examples).